# Search Bar Through Another Search Bar

Tags: search

I am not familiar with scripts that utilize this, so searching through Google gave me no valuable results.

To explain what I want let's make an example:

1. I have a search bar on my example website
2. A user inputs something and clicks search
3. The search bar does a series of searches, not on the website, but on other website's search bars, like a macro or a script of some sort. Then on my example websites, the search results of each page are listed

I have no idea how to even search for this, don't even know if there is a tutorial about whatever I am looking for. Any sort of pointers, or even links are appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why would you search through other site's search bars, and not just through their web services or APIs, which is what their search bars are doing?  Why not just add Google to your site?  It's all the search engine most people need.  And it's free.  Even if this is not a full solution to your need, put this in place while you are researching, and I doubt anyone will know the difference.

http://www.google.com/cse/

Comment: A global google search isn't what my website needs. I have 4-6 websites and their products. My website is an intermediary between clients and their products. Can you point me towards some tutorial or some reading material about using other website's APIs?

Comment: The custom google search is not a global search, you can specify which sites you are searching.  Click on this link.  You would put your 4-6 sites in the definition of your search engine and that is your custom solution.  http://www.google.com/cse/manage/create

Comment: Thanks. I see. So I can use this to list the few websites I need and then somehow modify the website to refer to this search?

Comment: Hmm, I've tried what you suggested. While its good on its own, it doesn't really work the way I want. Its searching for everything with the keywords. This is why I said browsing the search bar, that is how the results page would list only products of the sort, not forum discussions, headlines, news etc...

Comment: Well, it was worth a shot, maybe someone else will come along with a solution.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Even though it didn't solve my problem, it specified what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

First, in each of these sites, you will need to preform a search by hand (just search whatever) then record the URL of the page once you hit submit.
The URL should contain the word you searched in some fashion.

What you can do on your site when someone performs a search is you inject their search into each of those URLs you collected.
Then, you can use a thing called cURL to fetch the contents of those web pages.

Once you have the contents of each of those pages, I suggest you use regular expressions to only grab a portion of the page that you want to display (or even just product page URLs).

Comment: of course, this is assuming you don't have direct access to the databases behind these sites.

Comment: Great, I'll give this a try see if I get stuck somewhere